# How to view all cache records in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, caching, eloquent

I have records in a tag cache, but I'm not sure what the cache keys for the various records are. If I do `php artisan tinker` to see the records in the cache I can see:

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> \Cache::tags('my_tag_name');
=> Illuminate\Cache\RedisTaggedCache {#2355}
```

I would like to inspect some of these cached records, but I don't know the cache keys for the records. How can I see the records in the cache or list out the cache keys for the records?

Ultimately I'd like to view the records like

```
>>> \Cache::tags('my_tag_name')->get('someCacheKeyHere');
```

But not sure how to view the cache keys for the records with the tag "my_tag_name". How can I list out the records in the Laravel cache?

Comment: Have a look through the Laravel API directory: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.html (I believe the `Cache::` facade resolves to that class, since the `cache()` global helper does)

Comment: Check out https://github.com/illuminate/cache. I think you might be able to do `\Cache::tags('my_tag_name')->getTags()->getNames()` or recreate the protected `tagIds()` function in `TagSet`.

Comment: If the above doesn't work, you can get the prefix for the tags using the above, and then manually exec `KEYS $tag_prefix*` on the store connection itself.

Comment: RedisStore does not have a method "getTags". The prefix for this tag is generated dynamically so it's not something I can search in redis itself

Comment: @ConnorLeech Does `Cache::tags('my_tag_name')->getStore()->getPrefix()` return the key prefix you're looking for?